# Install an npm package and "ReferenceError:Window in undefined" get occurs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stompjs

I'm working on a React project and tried to install @Stomp/stompjs package which uses the window object under the hood. At the first place,  that I run the project the below error occurs:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined   
 at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/.../node_modules/@stomp/stompjs/bundles/webpack:/StompJs/webpack/universalModuleDefinition:10:2)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:30)
```

to solve this problem head over to many solutions across the web, but could not fix the bug.. here's some of my solution that didn't work:

1. I set 'globalobject' in the output sections of the webpack to different values ..this, window, global, etc.
2. lazy import of the package